# Cheerio changing single quotas into double

Tags: html, node.js, cheerio

I am using cheerio to modify HTML that i am scraping from a website. However it is messing up quoats.

This script works fine, the only issue is, it is changing ' to "

```
       // Load in HTML
       $ = cheerio.load(string);
       console.log($.html());
```

It is changing:

```
     <script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src='//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0967/6522/t/2/assets/jquery.min.js?15981737959390328713'>\x3C/script>")</script>
```

To:

```
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write("<script src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0967/6522/t/2/assets/jquery.min.js?15981737959390328713">\x3C/script>")</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you ran into issue [#720](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/issues/720) on the Cheerio issue tracker. They said they won't fix it, but you might convince them with your use case. I suggest commenting on the issue there.